# Filtering a specific column in my R dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

I want to make a for-loop in R with the following code. I tried a lot approaches but it did not work. Got someone an idea how to create a for-loop for this without repetitive code? And sorry if this is a really stupid question.

```
#x[,4]
#[1] 234 788 211 350 532 98 77 45 123 900 135 841 283 15 421 19 643 934
```

Above is a part of the column that I want to filter.
I would like to filter this with the code below.

```
xmin_15_xmax_100 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (100)),]
xmin_15_xmax_200 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (200)),]
xmin_15_xmax_300 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (300)),]
xmin_15_xmax_400 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (400)),]
xmin_15_xmax_500 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (500)),]
xmin_15_xmax_600 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (600)),]
xmin_15_xmax_700 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (700)),]
xmin_15_xmax_800 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (800)),]
xmin_15_xmax_900 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (900)),]
xmin_15_xmax_1000 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 15 & x[,4] <= (1000)),]

xmin_20_xmax_100 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (100)),]
xmin_20_xmax_200 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (200)),]
xmin_20_xmax_300 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (300)),]
xmin_20_xmax_400 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (400)),]
xmin_20_xmax_500 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (500)),]
xmin_20_xmax_600 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (600)),]
xmin_20_xmax_700 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (700)),]
xmin_20_xmax_800 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (800)),]
xmin_20_xmax_900 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (900)),]
xmin_20_xmax_1000 <- x[which(x[,4] >= 20 & x[,4] <= (1000)),]

#until xmin_30 and max_1000
# xmin <- steps by 5
# xmax <- steps by 100
```

If you need any more information, please let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: Doing this with `for` loops for this is easy. You should be able to do that after reading An Introduction to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you are after, does it?

```
mins <- c(15, 20); maxs <- seq(100, 1000, by = 100)
combs <- expand.grid(mins,maxs)
for(i in 1:nrow(combs)){
  x_iter <- x[x[,4] >= combs[i,1] & x[,4] <= combs[i,2], ]

  # do here whatever you want to do on x_iter

}
```

Comment: Yes, almost. This gives me only a dataframe with mins = 20 and maxs = 1000. And I also want dataframes with the other combinations

Comment: It does iterate over all combinations.

Comment: Yeah but it only saves the last iteration in x_iter. However, it is working like a charm with capture.output. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Then you should store it in a prespecified object. As Roland suggests above, find yourself a good introduction to R, this will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: vectorizing the `between` function from the dplyr or the data.table package:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:1000, 100)
vbetween <- Vectorize(dplyr::between, vectorize.args = c("left", "right"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
lapply(vbetween(x, rep(10, 2), c(100, 200)), which)
# [[1]]
# [1] 10 27 47 55 56 69 92
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10 12 24 27 34 38 47 55 56 69 86 88 90 92
```